# How can I redirect a concrete5 website to addon domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, concrete5, addon-domain

I installed concrete5 CMS in main domain folder and created an addon domain pointing to the main domain, but after creating the full website, when I redirect it from cpanel, the navigation is not working at all. You can see it by clicking following link:

the link where I build the site: http://www.venturescontracting.com/venturestowing
after redirect the addon domain http://www.venturestowing.com/

Please help me. How can I permanently redirect to the addon domain correctly?

Comment: In questions asking for code, please provide us with what you tried so far, and what happened when you tried it.

Comment: do you want both domains to work, or are you trying to move the site to the new domain?

Answer (score 0):

Edit update:  Oops. Looks like this is all fixed now.  All okay?  Original note follows, as the concept of "subdomains all" makes some sense...

Have you seen this [link on best practices](http://www.concrete5.org/documentation/how-tos/developers/organise-your-concrete5-web-space-for-risk-free-upgrades/) for hosting multiple concrete5 domains?  Basically you place each 'site' in a separate directory, such that no one site his hosted at the root (public_html)... Everything is in subfolders from the root directory, and registered as a subdomain.  Then you point the domain A-record to the IP address of your hosting site.   Your hosting site (which appears to be Godaddy) can help you do this.  They have pretty good tech support via phone 24x7